# Не удается подключиться к локальному серверу через SQL Server Authentication

Tags: sql-server, ssms

При попытке подключиться к локальному серверу, используя SQL Server Authentication вылезает ошибка 233:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При повторной попытке подключиться уже 18456:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На сервере есть логин `MIS ADMIN`, через который я пытаюсь подключаться к нему:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Параметр `login` в `Status` переведен в `enabled`.

В настройках сервера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно подключиться к локальному серверу через созданный на нем логин?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, делал я все по алгоритму, с учетом всех деталей, но все равно не работало.

Помогла перезагрузка компьютера, на следующий день все заработало. Также, возможно, заработало после поставленной галочки на `Remember password`.